# Swift cannot import SwiftyJSON and Alamofire by cocoapods on Xcode 8

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode8, swifty-json

I need use SwiftyJSON and Alamofire in my Swift project, so I use cocoapods.

My podfile is :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'SwiftSalt' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Also, I did add a USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS , $(PODS_ROOT)/**.

But, it still didn't work. It says "No such module 'SwiftyJSON'". What does module mean?

Answer (score 0):

Change config.build_settings to swift 2.3. Because swiftyJSON is still on swift 2.3

```
 post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
end
```

end

Comment: where can i find it?

Comment: Alamofire support Swift 3.0, should I seperate them?

Comment: Yeah SwiftyJSON not supported to 3.0. Yeah try it :)

Comment: SWIFTYjson has 3.0 branch, try to install that pod

Comment: I mean if I wrote 3.0, both would be 3.0. If I wrote 2.3, both would be 2.3. I don't know how to separate them. I don't know the cocoapods grammar.

Comment: just use my answer, alamofire supports 2.3. I also don't know how to separate :(

Comment: I do use your podfile, but still lots of errors in alamofire. Don't know why.

Comment: Did you update your cocoapods ?, don't use , '~> 4.0' in alamorfire

Comment: And how can I switch the version among SwiftyJSON's two branches. The two branches are master and swift3. And I think SwiftyJSON Swift 3.0 version is unstable.

Comment: Then just use 2.3 of both cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Used the following podfile to install the Swift 3 branch of SwiftyJSON, and it worked on the project:

```
  platform :ios, ’10.0’

  project ‘/Users/You/yourproject.xcodeproj’

  target 'yourproject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/appsailor/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
  end

  post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
           end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/appsailor/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```